# Why does h1 tag not center in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

Creating a responsive website and for some reason when going into mobile view, the 'ORGANIZATIONS' header does not center.

For some reason it doesn't recognize the S expanded and will not center.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHKnW.png)

Comment: One possibility is you may have horizontal margin/padding in the container or so its acutual size is smaller than it looks like, and `ORGANIZATIONS` is too long to fit in. Try to inspect it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
Kindly add the code in your question to debug us the exact problem, may be you have added some padding, or margin.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>London is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,
  with a metropolitan area of over 9 million inhabitants.</p>
</div>
```

add css to this container such as

```
.container{
text-align:center;
}
```

this will be a responsive code and thus it will be aligned to center in the mobile view also.